# How to pass a default query param with Rails 2.3.x routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do something trivial. I have a bunch of URLs that I need to map like the following:

`http://example.com/foo`
`http://example.com/foo/something`

Both need to go to the same controller/action. The problem I'm having is when `http://example.com/foo` is invoked, I need to specify a default query parameter. I thought that's what the :defaults hash does in routes.rb, but unfortunately the following doesn't work:

```
map.connect 'foo', :controller => 'something', :action => 'anaction', 
  :defaults => { :myparam => 'foobar' }
```

This should route `http://example.com/foo` to the something controller, anaction action, and make params[:myparam] point to the string "foobar".

I'm assuming for the second example `http://example.com/foo/something`, I'll need an additional route.

What's the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but:

```
map.connect 'foo', :controller => 'something', :action => 'anaction', :myparam => 'foobar'
```

It looks like the `:controller` and `:action` arguments in there are not in any way special, but just end up feeding into `params`. [The 2.3.8 documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Routing.html) seems to confirm this.

> More formally, you can include
>   arbitrary parameters in the route,
>   thus:
>
> ```
> map.connect ':controller/:action/:id', :action => 'show', :page => 'Dashboard'
> ```
>
> This will
>   pass the :page parameter to all
>   incoming requests that match this
>   route.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't complicate things by adding such logic to my routes file, I'd just do it in my action:

```
params[:my_param] ||= 'foobar'
```

Comment: Worked for me -- and it's Rails 3 compatible! :P